# How can I redirect to admin/login page from another page outside application folder in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have some files I created outside application folder in codeigniter. Below is the structure of my folders and files[image]

**sys_config.php** is the default file which redirects to either **b0a.php** or admin/login under **application folder** if a condition is met.

**sys_config.php code**

```
 $sql ="SELECT host FROM tray WHERE host = '$host'";

       $ret = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
       $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ret);

      if ($row['host'] != '' && $row['host'] == $host) {

        redirect("index", true);
    } else {
        //echo "<p>Nothing matched your query.</p>";
        redirect("b02.php", true);

    }
```

In install.php under controller, I have this

```
<?php

Class Install extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        //load in some helpers
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'file', 'url','language'));

        if($this->session->userdata('lang')!="")
        {
            $this->lang->load('admin',$this->session->userdata('lang'));
        }else{
            $this->lang->load('admin', 'english');
        }

        //if this system is already installed redirect to the homepage
        if(file_exists(FCPATH.'application/config/setup.php'))
        {
            //redirect('admin/login');
            redirect('sys_config');
        }

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('session');
    }

    function index()
    {
        //build our checks
        $data = array();
        //Destroy All Session
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        //check for writable folders
        $data['is_writeable']['root'] = is_writeable(FCPATH);
        $data['is_writeable']['config'] = is_writeable(FCPATH.'application/config/');
        $data['is_writeable']['uploads'] = is_writeable(FCPATH.'uploads/');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('hostname', 'Hostname', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('database', 'Database Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('prefix', 'Database Prefix', 'trim');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('ssl_support');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mod_rewrite');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $data['errors'] = validation_errors();
            $this->load->view('install', $data);
        }
        else
        {
            // Unset any existing DB information
            unset($this->db);

            //generate a dsn string
            $dsn = 'mysqli://'.$this->input->post('username').':'.$this->input->post('password').'@'.$this->input->post('hostname').'/'.$this->input->post('database');

            //connect!
            $this->load->database($dsn);

            if (is_resource($this->db->conn_id) OR is_object($this->db->conn_id))
            {
                //setup the database config file
                $settings                   = array();
                $settings['hostname']       = $this->input->post('hostname');
                $settings['username']       = $this->input->post('username');
                $settings['password']       = $this->input->post('password');
                $settings['database']       = $this->input->post('database');
                $settings['prefix']         = $this->input->post('prefix');             
                $file_contents              = $this->load->view('templates/database', $settings, true);
                write_file(FCPATH.'application/config/database.php', $file_contents);
                $setup_file = "//This Is Setup File";
                write_file(FCPATH.'application/config/setup.php',$setup_file);
                //setup the CodeIgniter default config file

                $config_index               = array('index'=>'index.php');
                if($this->input->post('mod_rewrite'))
                {
                    $config_index           = array('index'=>'');
                }
                $file_contents              = $this->load->view('templates/config', $config_index, true);
                write_file(FCPATH.'application/config/config.php', $file_contents);



                //setup the .htaccess file
                if($this->input->post('mod_rewrite'))
                {
                    $subfolder = trim(str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', FCPATH), '/').'/';
                    $file_contents              = $this->load->view('templates/htaccess', array('subfolder'=>$subfolder), true);
                    write_file(FCPATH.'.htaccess', $file_contents);
                }
                $this->load->library('migration');

                if ( ! $this->migration->current())
                {
                    show_error($this->migration->error_string());
                }

                //redirect to the admin login
                redirect('register');
            }
            else
            {
                $data['errors'] = '<p>A connection to the database could not be established.</p>';
                $this->load->view('install', $data);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I redirect to sys_config which is outside application folder using:

```
//if this system is already installed redirect to the homepage
        if(file_exists(FCPATH.'application/config/setup.php'))
        {
            //redirect('admin/login');
            redirect('sys_config');
        }
```

Everything worked fine. But now I tried to redirect back to admin/login which gives me:

> This page isn’t working localhost redirected you too many times. Try
>   clearing your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

**index.php**

```
<?php

    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * ERROR REPORTING
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 */

if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
        break;

        case 'testing':
        case 'production':
            error_reporting(0);
        break;

        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * SYSTEM FOLDER NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 */
    $system_path = 'system';

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION FOLDER NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 */
    $application_folder = 'application';


    // Set the current directory correctly for CLI requests
    if (defined('STDIN'))
    {
        chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
    }

    if (realpath($system_path) !== FALSE)
    {
        $system_path = realpath($system_path).'/';
    }

    // ensure there's a trailing slash
    $system_path = rtrim($system_path, '/').'/';

    // Is the system path correct?
    if ( ! is_dir($system_path))
    {
        exit("Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: ".pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));
    }

/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Now that we know the path, set the main path constants
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
    // The name of THIS file
    define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));

    // The PHP file extension
    // this global constant is deprecated.
    define('EXT', '.php');

    // Path to the system folder
    define('BASEPATH', str_replace("\\", "/", $system_path));

    // Path to the front controller (this file)
    define('FCPATH', str_replace(SELF, '', __FILE__));

    // Name of the "system folder"
    define('SYSDIR', trim(strrchr(trim(BASEPATH, '/'), '/'), '/'));


    // The path to the "application" folder
    if (is_dir($application_folder))
    {
        define('APPPATH', $application_folder.'/');
    }
    else
    {
        if ( ! is_dir(BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/'))
        {
            exit("Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: ".SELF);
        }

        define('APPPATH', BASEPATH.$application_folder.'/');
    }

require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';

/* End of file index.php */
/* Location: ./index.php */
```

Please, how can I redirect from **sys_config.php** to admin/login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should exclude the url to your `admin/login` from redirection check .. because what's happening here is that it gets redirected to `admin/login` which i believe it has a check for login then redirect method if not logged in which is not met so it gets redirected to the referrer and so on ..

In you check add if the uri segment string equals `admin/login` then don't redirect.